# PHP shortcode input variable

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm displaying a gallery on my wordpress site using the following code:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[satellite gallery=2 auto=off caption=off thumbs=on]'); ?>
```

Now I've added a custom post value/field called 'guitLink' where I can add the gallery number which I want to then use in the above shortcode, so something like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[satellite gallery=' .get_post_custom_values('guitLink'). 'auto=off caption=off thumbs=on]'); ?>
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
<?php $guitLink = get_post_custom_values('guitLink');
echo do_shortcode('[satellite gallery=' .$guitLink[0]. ' auto=off caption=off thumbs=on]'); ?>
```

Instead of

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[satellite gallery=' .get_post_custom_values('guitLink'). ' auto=off caption=off thumbs=on]'); ?>
```

Comment: get_post_custom_values('guitLink'); returns array instead of single value